# Upload image within ng-submit form

Tags: angularjs, forms, upload

I'm new to Angular.js and I would like to know how to upload an image within my ng-submit form. It works perfectly for the next based fields but with the file it only gives me the 'choose file' button without displaying it after hitting the submit button.

```
<form ng-submit="addartikel()">
<input type="text" placeholder="Bezeichnung" ng-model="newartikel.name" />
<input type="text" placeholder="Kategorie" ng-model="newartikel.kategorie" />
<input type="text" placeholder="Preis" ng-model="newartikel.preis" />
<input type="file" placeholder="Bild" ng-model="newartikel.thumb" />
<input type="submit" value="Artikel hinzufügen" />
```

As for the controller:

```
    webShop.controller('InventarController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){

  $scope.addartikel = function(){
    $scope.inventar.push({
      name: $scope.newartikel.name,
      kategorie: $scope.newartikel.kategorie,
      preis: parseInt($scope.newartikel.preis),
      thumb: $scope.newartikel.thumb,
      available: true
    });
```

Your help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Angular File Upload.It is available in https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload